# Input string was not in a correct format occurs in c#

Tags: c#, textbox

```
    private void txtbox_BattMmnt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back /*|| e.KeyChar == (char)5*/ || e.KeyChar == 46)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }           
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Only Numeric Value", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        double i=Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_BattMmnt.Text);
        if (i >=2.9 || i <= 3.35)
        { e.Handled = false; }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Only from 2.9 to 3.35", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

The error appears in  `double i=Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_BattMmnt.Text);`
What shall I do? I tried Regex but it wont satisfy my range of values to be entered in the text box.

Comment: Why don't you use `Double.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToDouble`?

Comment: What is the value of `txtbox_BattMmnt.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: @SonerGönül Value of textbox are voltage values of battery.. i dont know abt Currentculture.. im very new to c# and coding

Comment: ill try and say abt Double.TryParse.. thanks in advance @DmitryBychenko

Comment: never name a double "i", use "d" instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private void txtbox_BattMmnt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back /*|| e.KeyChar == (char)5*/ || e.KeyChar == 46)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Only Numeric Value", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;//return if it is not numeric.
    }
    double i = 0;
    Double.TryParse(txtbox_BattMmnt.Text, out i);
    if (i <= 2.9 || i >= 3.35)
    { e.Handled = false; }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Only from 2.9 to 3.35", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks... but i tried this.. when i debug its not even going in the else command...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double d;
if(!double.TryParse(txtbox_BattMmnt.Text, out d))
{
    // invalid text in textbox, not convertable to double
}
```

This allows for arbitrary user input without crashing your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void txtbox_BattMmnt_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbox_BattMmnt = (TextBox)sender;
        double d; Double.TryParse(txtbox_BattMmnt.Text, out d);
        if ((d <= 2.8) || (d >= 3.36))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Only from 2.9 to 3.35", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        txtbox_BattMmnt.Text = String.Empty;

    }
```

**I tried this.....it worked out. thank u guys**